# Automatic Token Distribution?

Tags: token, voting

Is there a way to automatically distribute a token to every wallet that holds ada?

This would be a mechanism to distribute DAO voting rights automatically to all ada wallets. Voting power would be proportional to the amount of ada in the wallet. 1 DAO token per 10000 ADA. A wallet owner could choose to either burn the token or sell them to someone else if they are not interested in participating in the DAO.

Could this be executed in a single trasaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about all ADA wallets that exist, this is certainly not possible in a single transaction.
If there are 142 addresses or less (that you are distributing to), it should be possible in a single transaction, otherwise the transaction size will be too large (above the 16 KB limit). You also need to send about 1.3 ADA (depending on the token name and the amount of tokens you send) to each address together with the tokens.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information.